# Exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to determine request start time'

Tags: debugging, yii2

When I try to use debug module in Yii2 - I get this error - Exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to determine request start time'

I can't find, how to solve it.
Have you any ideas?

Comment: The debug module tries to read data a file runtime/debug/xxxxxx.data . Do those folders and such file exist? Folders must be writable for the web server. Though, I would expect other error messages if this is not the case...

Comment: Please describe if you any special debug configuration settings.

Comment: On which is your system running? I've just read that for the debug Timeline panel (which probably causes your error) PHP's [microtime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) must work. You could make a simple test to see if it works.

Comment: Maybe, I used old version of yii2-debug? After installed https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-debug I have Exception: Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unknown component ID: log'

Comment: I used debug before and it worked - therefore folders is writeable for the web server

Comment: I have no special config settings for debug - just exactly like on repo page - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-debug

Comment: I running on Linux. Right now I have no that Exception, but if it will appear again - I will try to test with microtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! I figured it out!!!
I added 
`'enableDebugLogs' => true,`
 in config - after
`'class' => yii\debug\Module::class,`

Comment: I think this is a workaround and not the actual problem. But if it helps it is okay!

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your comments!